# Reason for key error being returned when if statement is ordered differently?

Tags: python

Code and context:

Intro to python course on data quest exercise. Applestore.csv contains data on apps in the appstore and task is to create a dictionary containing the age rating as the key and frequency as the value.

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
content_ratings={}
for rows in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating=rows[10]
    if c_rating in content_ratings==false:
        content_ratings.update({c_rating:1})
    else:
        content_ratings[c_rating]+=1
print(content_ratings)
```

I dont understand why the above gives me a key error, while the below works fine:

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
content_ratings={}
for rows in apps_data[1:]:
    c_ratings=rows[10]
    if c_ratings in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[c_ratings]+=1
    else: 
        content_ratings.update({c_ratings:1})
print(content_ratings)
```

In the above case I believe I am saying that if c_rating is not present as a key then update the dictionary to make the key value pair else, just add 1 to the value.

In the second case I believe I am saying if the key is already present add 1 to the value else update the dictionary with the key value pair.

Why does the latter work over the former?

Comment: What is `false`? `False`?

Comment: `c_rating in content_ratings==false` will never be true. These kinds of operators chain in Python: it's equivalent to `c_rating in content_ratings and content_ratings==false`

Comment: `== false` is typically superfluous in almost all other languages too, in Python it has a non-obvious meaning on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c_rating in content_ratings==false` will never be true. These kinds of operators chain in Python: it's equivalent to `c_rating in content_ratings and content_ratings==false`

You could write

```
if (c_rating in content_ratings) == False:
```

but the correct way to write it would be

```
if c_rating not in content_ratings:
```

Better, you could replace the whole if/else with

```
content_rating[c_rating] = content_rating.get(c_rating, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is evaluated as `if (c_rating in content_ratings) and (content_ratings==False)`. Since the second condition is always False, the whole expression is always false, too, triggering the execution of the `else` branch, regardless of whether `c_rating` is in the dictionary or not.